# Missing labels in multi tasks network

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I am working on a multi tasks learning problem where I have 3 different tasks to solve:

- A multi label classification problem `p1` where I have a labels vector `v1` of size `s1` where I have a 1 for each correct label, 0 otherwise.
- A multi label classification problem `p2` where I have a labels vector `v2` of size `s2` where I have a 1 for each correct label, 0 otherwise.
- A single label classification problem `p3` where I have a labels vector `v3` of size `s3` where I have a 1 for the correct label, 0 otherwise.

The issue I encounter is that for each example I can have one or two problems where the labels are not defined. For instance I could have:

```
v1 = [0,1,1,0]
v2 = [1,0,1,0,0,1]
v3 = [0,0,0]
```

where labels in `v3` are missing. My question is how to block the backprop for the problems with missing labels so that the weights of the network are not updated on missing data?

For now my code looks like something like this:

```
target1 = tf.cast(labels['1'], tf.float32)
loss1 = tf.reduce_mean(
    tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(
        labels=target1, logits=logits1))

target2 = tf.cast(labels['2'], tf.float32)
loss2 = tf.reduce_mean(
    tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(
        labels=target2, logits=logits2))

target3 = tf.cast(labels['3'], tf.float32)
loss3 = tf.reduce_mean(
    tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
        labels=target3, logits=logits3))

loss = loss1 + loss2 + loss3
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(
                loss, global_step=global_step)
```

My idea would be to set a weight at 0 for each example with missing labels but I don't really know if it is a viable solution, especially in the case where I get a full batch with only missing labels for a  problem.

I can fill the vectors with missing values to -1 or anything else if this can help!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If there are no labels, why is that input in the training set at all?  There is no learning to be had from that vector.  Remove those from the training set before you start.

Comment: it is a multi taks network. That means I can have labels for one example for 2 tasks and not the third one, thus I don't want to remove it since it brings information on 2 of the three tasks!

Comment: I see; the tasks are not independent.

Comment: They are and i can't really use several optimizers because the presence of particular labels in the example stream is statically unknown..

Comment: I disagree: if you are forced to process a zero-vector **v3** simply because there is information in **v1** or **v2**, then the tasks are not independent.  However, this is semantics -- we need to attack the functional problem.

Comment: Sorry I meant they are dependent, my bad!

Comment: What sort of model topology do you have?  Is this three separate training flows?  Single-vector or batch training (which affects the back-prop)?  Can you supply a diagram?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the type of network you have, and perhaps whether you have batch or individual training.  I assume that your internal network is three independent

If your training is individual, then setting weights to zero will work.  You could get the same effect by setting the learning rate to 0 for that BP (back-propagation) iteration.

Another possibility is to check the input vector at the first layer; if it's zero, then don't enter that phase of training at all; a simple **continue** should take you to the next input iteration.